# textview drawable right animation

Tags: android

I noticed that textview have drawable top/bottom/left/right. And you can set it in the code using setCompundDrawable.

I know I can use whats below to create drawable animation (framees one after the other) when I have imageview.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html

However, how can I do it for the drawable of the textview (Drawable Right for example)?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TextView` doesn't allow access to compound drawables via getter. So you can add animation in next way, from the link you have shared:
rocket_thrust.xml

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="true">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rocket_thrust1" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rocket_thrust2" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rocket_thrust3" android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>
```

And here is code that can run animation in `TextView` as left drawable:

```
AnimationDrawable rocketAnimation;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  rocketAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rocket_thrust);
  rocketAnimation.setBounds(0, 0, rocketAnimation.getIntrinsicWidth(), rocketAnimation.getIntrinsicHeight());

  TextView rocketText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
  rocketText.setCompoundDrawables(rocketAnimation, null, null, null);
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
  if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    rocketAnimation.start();
    return true;
  }
  return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

if you are working with drawable from the code you need to specify drawable bounds. In case of image drawables you can relay on `getIntrinsicWidth`, `getIntrinsicHeight` otherwise you need to specify some dimensions.